# UNIX config files, load conf-unix-mode

Tags: init-file, linux, config

I work a lot with unix config files (i.e the files in */etc* in the various linux system) that have no extension. How can I set-up my .emacs file to load conf-unix-mode on those files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean specifically "all files in the `/etc/` directory," you could add an absolute path to your `auto-mode-alist`:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/etc/.*" . conf-unix-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful suggestion. Is there a way to  apply this rule to all the config files? Should I replace `"/etc/.*"`  with `"/.*"` ?

Comment: Maybe to avoid conflicts with files with known extensions something like this would be better: `"/etc/.*/[^\.]+$"`.

Comment: @wvxvw: I tried your solution but do not seems to work as expected. I tried the approach proposed by Dan and it works better also with my change. I also added some exceptions using a similar string.

Comment: Well, the thing Dan suggested will match files like `/etc/ant.conf`, `/etc/aliases.db` and so on, while what I am suggesting will only match `/etc/aliases` for example (i.e. if there is an extension, then it won't match).