# How do I force a mode on a specific file through special comments

Tags: major-mode

I have a file called `zshrc` (not `.zshrc`). Emacs does not recognize that it must use `sh-mode`automatically. I want to put some sort of hint for emacs to pick up and syntax highlight my file accordingly.

how do I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNIX config files, load conf-unix-mode](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16343/unix-config-files-load-conf-unix-mode)

Comment: You can use the example above and use `auto-mode-alist` to set `"zshrc\\'"` to `sh-mode`.

Comment: @KaushalModi no, it's not a duplicate — the other post is about setting a mode in all files in a directory.

Comment: @jch I that that it does not matter. The core question is how to set "foo" files in "bar" mode. In the former case, you needed to put the dir in the regexp, in this latter case, you need to put the filename.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a
[file-local variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables)
to specify the mode.

You can either put them at the top of the file, like so:

```
# -*- mode: sh -*-
```

or at the bottom of the file, like so:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: sh
# End:
```

Comment: I have tried this method using `// -*- mode: php -*-` in a PHP file with a non-standard extension but it doesn't seem to work. Have I got the syntax wrong? `//` is a valid PHP comment prefix